# PHP | Call an API multiple times as a different link and get the data

Tags: php, api

PHP beginner here.

I want to call an API multiple times in a loop and save data out of these loops. The API source link has to change according to existing arrays everytime it will be called.

Example

```
$myArrays = array(
     'SYMBOL1' => array ( 'balance' => 14.90, 'boughtprice' => 630 ),
     'SYMBOL2' => array ( 'balance' => 12.90, 'boughtprice' => 3730 ),
     'SYMBOL3' => array ( 'balance' => 11.90, 'boughtprice' => 42 )
     );    



$ApiData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://Exampledata/Data='.$symbol.'example-settings=30'), true);
```

I got 3 Symbols in my arrays, so I want to go trough the API 3 times, but the first time it has to be called with `$symbol` as `SYMBOL1`, and save data out of the result. Then call it again with `$symbol` as `SYMBOL2`, and again save data out of it and so on. In the End I need to have the saved data aviable as variables to do further calculations.

How is this achievable the easiest way?

Comment: do not use `file_get_content()` for network access. use cURL.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thanks for your comment, I will read into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a foreach and store data in an array

```
$myArrays = array(
     'SYMBOL1' => array ( 'balance' => 14.90, 'boughtprice' => 630 ),
     'SYMBOL2' => array ( 'balance' => 12.90, 'boughtprice' => 3730 ),
     'SYMBOL3' => array ( 'balance' => 11.90, 'boughtprice' => 42 )
     );    

$ApiData = array();
foreach($myArrays as $symbol => $value){
    $ApiData[] = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://Exampledata/Data='.$symbol.'example-settings=30'), true); 
}

var_dump($ApiData); //Your results are stored in $ApiData
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, with this code example, $symbol is a variable for "Array" and not for SYMBOL1, 2 or 3. So I get an error with calling the API because the link is broken. Any Ideas?

Comment: @cmdReligion I updated my answer, try now and let me know